# What is the best way to reduce the poly count on this object with smooth shading

Tags: polycount

Hi I have used decimate before but is there a better way to reduce the polygons on an object such as the one in image 1?

Image 1
[image: Subdivision 2 has been applied to this object]

Comment: Decimate set to Unsubdivide method and even number of iterations should be good enough to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same result as in cgslav's answer is a little more tedious in Blender 2.79 but just as easy. The starting object:

[image]

Duplicate the Object and hide the new object. Make sure the copy that is still visible is selected. Enable AutoSmooth in the Object Data Tab in the Properties Panel.

[image]

Add a Bevel Modifier and a Data Transfer Modifier. Set the other Cube as the Source Object, turn on Face Corner Data and set it to Projected Face Interpolated. Turn on Custom Normals and tweak the Bevel width to your liking. Segments needs to be an odd number for it to work, however there is probably no need for 3 or more Segments.

[image]

The final object has smooth shading and a minimal amount of Polygon. You can do the same steps in Blender 2.8, but checking Harden Normals in the Bevel settings as cgslav suggested is indeed a legit shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: final]

I see that you are using Blender 2.8 so you can make this object super low poly with new features in **Bevel** modifier.

**Object:**

You can create object in two ways. **Quad based** (edge loops) or simple **Boolean**.

[image: object]

**Modifier:**

Add **Bevel** modifier, check **Harden Normals**, switch mode to **Angle** and optionally change **Outer Miter** to **Arc**.

[image: bevel]

To be able to see the result, you will need to turn on **Autosmooth** and of course **Shading Smooth**.

[image: autosmooth]

Comment: Thanks cgslav nice modifier. Managed to get it working great.

Comment: @Mixstah If you consider my answer good enough you can accept and upvote it ;)

Comment: The boolean still gets you using NGons

Comment: @IAmGettingTiredOfAliases well, of course it will. This is why I've separated it between quad based and boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If this object is a pure Catmull-Clark subdivided object you can try my unsubdivide script ;)

You can get at https://blenderartists.org/t/reverse-catmull-clark-subdivision/443634/33